# Import Maven Libraries in OSGi Package

Tags: java, maven, osgi

I generated an OSGi Project with

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate \
    -DarchetypeGroupId=org.osgi.enroute.archetype \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=project \
    -DarchetypeVersion=7.0.0
```

Afterwards I tried to add some maven dependencies at the impl project.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.iot.raspberry</groupId>
        <artifactId>GrovePi-spec</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
         <groupId>org.iot.raspberry</groupId>
         <artifactId>GrovePi-pi4j</artifactId>
         <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

But maven always prints out `Unable to resolve <<INITIAL>>: missing requirement osgi.identity;filter:='(osgi.identity=com.itemis.raspberry.impl)' [caused by: Unable to resolve com.itemis.raspberry.impl version=1.0.0.201903061404: missing requirement osgi.wiring.package;filter:='(&(osgi.wiring.package=org.iot.raspberry.grovepi))']`

did someone know why this happens?

Comment: I guess that the dependencies you added maybe contain the org.iot.raspberry.grovepi package but none of them actually export that package through their MANIFEST.MF file. If this is the case, you have to amend the dependencies and export the packages you need through the Export-Package directive

Comment: ok, the package is in the manifest file but private. `Private-Package: com.itemis.raspberry.raspberry.io` is this an issue?

Comment: Yes, private package means the package cannot be used outside the defining bundle: you must export it (if it makes sense doing so from a modularity point of view). By the way, from the error you reported, the package to check is org.iot.raspberry.grovepi

Comment: I agree with the above, except that the error indicates you shouldn't be using the package `org.iot.raspberry.grovepi` because it is marked as private by the developer of the bundle. I'm assuming that `com.itemis.raspberry.impl` is your own bundle and the `org.iot.raspberry...` bundles are provided by a third party.

Comment: ok, thanks :-) I think I found the error :-)